# Using linq in .net core to parse a string and turn it into a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a string that gets input like say: `abcde`.

I then want to take that string and do the following:

1. Make the string uppercase
2. Parse the string to get each character one by one
3. Add a prefix to that new string (prefix is H-I)
4. Return a list of every new string in order.

So using `abcde` the resulting list should be:

```
// new list items being returned
H-IA
H-IB
H-IC
H-ID
H-IE
```

I know there should be an easy way to do this with `Linq` but don't quite have it yet.

Comment: Sounds awfully like a homework question. Stack overflow isn’t here to do your homework.

Comment: @SteveTodd Someone with 23K points won't be asking homework questions, trust me.

Comment: @TanveerBadaryou are very correct, I have not done homework since learning .NET ver. 1.0 my senior year - this question was more of a brain freeze as I have so many random tidbits of random languages floating around :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a line

```
var list = str.ToUpper().ToArray().Select(c => "H-1" + c).ToList();
```

Comment: dang that was so fast and simple. thx.